# How to send an email accepting or rejecting a request for a reservation

Tags: php, sql, phpmailer

My goal is to have the ability to accept or reject a request from a customer through email. What I have is the back office of my website, where it appears everyone that submitted to my reservation form, the customer after submitting receives an email saying that their confirmation is pending and at that moment is when the admin has the option to accept or reject the reservation, after that action is done, the customer would receive an email with the response.
Right now, I tried to do the "accept" button just to see if it would work. Right now, i get an error message saying that there's an invalid Address `$mail->addAddress($_POST['EmailReser']);`

```html
//File listreser.php

<body style="background-color:white;">
<?php
     $sql="select * from Reservas";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
?>

<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">List Reservations</h1> <br><br>      
  <table id ="tableUser"  class="table table-striped display">
    <thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Code of the reservation</th>
    <th>Name </th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>Date </th>
  <th>Time</th>
    <th>Number of people</th>
  <th>Message </th>
  <th>State</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 
while ($lin=$res->fetch_array()){ ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo$lin[Cod_Reserva]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[NomeReser]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[ApelidoReser]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[EmailReser]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[TelefoneR]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[DataR]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Hora]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[NumPessoas]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[MensagemR]; ?></td>     
 <td><a style="padding-right:12px;" href=index.php?cmd=aceitar&Cod_Reserva=<?php echo $lin["Cod_Reserva"]; ?>><img src='images/check.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a><a href=index.php?cmd=rejeitar&Cod_Reserva=<?php echo $lin["Cod_Reserva"]; ?>><img src='images/close.png' width="15" height = "15" ></td>

      </tr>
 <?php 
}
 ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```html
<?php
 var_dump($_GET);
 exit();
 // $Cod_Reserva=$_REQUEST['Cod_Reserva'];  
 $Cod_Reserva=$_REQUEST['Cod_Reserva'];
 //$EmailReser = $_GET['EmailReser'];
   // $sql="select * from Reservas ";
    $sql="select EmailReser from reservas where cod_reserva = $Cod_Reserva";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
 //$lin=$res->fetch_array();
  while ($lin=$res->fetch_array()){ 
 require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
 $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
 $mail->Username='email@gmail.com';
 $mail->Password='****';
 $mail->setFrom('email@gmail.com');
 $mail->addAddress($lin['EmailReser']);
 $mail->addReplyTo('email@gmail.com');
 
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject='Your request has been confirmed';
 $mail->Body = "message";
 
 if(!$mail->send()){
  echo "<script>
                alert('There's been a mistake');
              </script>";
 }
 else{  
   echo "<script>
                alert('Email was sent with success');

               </script>";
}
 
 }

?>
```

Comment: Submit buttons submit a form. You don’t appear to have any form here.

Comment: `<?php header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); ?>` - what sense is that supposed to make, especially after you already output HTML elements such as `<body>` …?

Comment: So I can just delete the `type="submit"` ? And use the rest?

Comment: `submit` is the default button type if it is missing, so if anything you would have to use `type="button"` if you want this to be a button that does not have the purpose to submit a form. But then still not much is going to happen, you would have to attach some JavaScript logic then before that button will do _anything_ when clicked.

Comment: So if I just used an icon instead of a button? Do you think it would work?

Comment: You need to either call your script via a link, or by submitting a form, or by making an AJAX request in the background, those are your three basic choices.

Comment: About the `if(isset($_POST['aceitar']))` how would I make it work? By making a function? Because if it was a button, it would know how to do it

Comment: Because I would like to make everything on that file because I don't know how to send the email for each row

Comment: If you want your button to submit a form, well then add a form …

Comment: The problem is I don't want a form, [check this link so you can see what my vision is](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/10/how-to-send-bulk-email-in-php-using.html)

Comment: Well that uses AJAX instead, to send the parameters to the server-side script.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do what he did, but with I did? Which means, a simpler version?

Comment: Many different things are “possible”, but all of them will more or less require that you have a basic idea of what you are doing to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your button with a link to a separate PHP script that sends the acceptance email. You'd need to include enough information to know which reservation you're accepting (and hence where to send it), and you'd need to add some validation to ensure that only suitable users can actually process the acceptance.

So something like just the end of your code

```
<a href='acceptance.php?ref=<?php echo $lin["Cod Reserva"]; ?>'>Accept</a>
```

to call that script and pass in that value as $_GET['ref'], for each row in your table. Sorry I don't know if that's the correct field to pass in, but it needs to be the unique ID for the reservation. Your acceptance.php script then retrieves the rest of the information from the database to get the email address to use.

Or you could draw a html form in each row, stick the reference in a hidden variable, draw a button, and have that call the separate script.

Sending the email in a separate script instead of the same one makes it easy to add Ajax later on for users that have JS enabled.

Comment: Okay so, I finally did it, but there's a little problem, it tells me there's a problem with this line of code `$mail->addAddress($_POST['EmailReser']);`, it says that it's an invalid email, problem is I don´t know how to solve it, because I want to send the email for the email selected

Comment: You haven't passed a `$_POST` array through because you didn't submit a form. So the only thing you passed through will come in the `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` arrays. You should then use the email address that you retrieve from the database based on the reservation unique ID that you passed through. You're missing an equal-sign in the URL as well.

Comment: Can you edit the post with your suggestion, please?

Comment: Based on the combination of code you posted, I'm going to guess that it should read `$mail->addAddress($lin['EmailReser'])` instead of using the `$_POST` variable. That's presuming you get the information through from the link and your query retrieves a record - you should probably check for that as part of your standard validation.

Comment: I did that, and after the `require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; ` i made a while `while ($lin=$res->fetch_array()){ `m which made it work, the problem is, i only get an email in one specific email, for example, if I click on A it sends emails A, if I click on B it send emails to B, if I click on C it send emails to A

Comment: I changed what I did, to what you suggested, but the same thing continues to happen

Comment: Actually now I look at your query, that just seems to retrieve all reservations. Shouldn't you have a "where" clause to only retrieve the specific reservation that you want to send the email to?

Comment: So... how would it be?

Comment: I'd have thought something like ```select EmailReser from reservas where cod_reserva = $Cod_Reserva```, though you'd be better using prepared statements than just concatenating the string. I'm presuming that `cod_reserva` is the unique id as that's the variable you pass in, and there's no need to retrieve anything other than the email address, no need for `*` in the query. But I'm guessing on the column names here. That should return only one row, so in theory you'd only need one `fetch_array()`, so no need for a `while` loop.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, I'm gonna edit my post the way that it is right now (the one that sends all the emails for  one specific email address)and you can make the changes you think may work

Comment: You've changed the name of the parameter that you retrieve the ID from in your PHP code, but you haven't changed it in the `href` where you call it. You also still haven't replaced the `=` sign in that `href`, so the URL won't parse properly. The link should read `<td><a href=index.php?cmd=aceitar&Cod_Reserva=<?php echo $lin["Cod_Reserva"]; ?>><img src='images/check.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a></td>` and the variable will come through in `$_GET['Cod_Reserva']` in your PHP code. I'd rather point you in the right direction than edit the code directly for you.

Comment: I changed everything and edited again the post, but I don't get what you meant by "but you haven't changed in the `href` " because the name is the same. It still doesn't work btw

Comment: In the version of your PHP code that was present earlier, you had commented out the reference to `$_GET['Cod_Reserva']`, and instead were trying to access `$_GET['EmailReser']`, but you don't pass this variable in your link, so it will always be blank. You pass in exactly two variables in your link - `cmd` (which you don't use anywhere) and `Cod_Reserva`, which I think is the unique ID for your reservation. You should use that in your query as I commented above to retrieve _only_ that one reservation, then use the email address that comes from it.

Comment: So maybe I should do something like `$Cod_Reserva=$_REQUEST['Cod_Reserva'];` (which yes is my ID) and then `select EmailReser from reservas where cod_reserva = $Cod_Reserva` ?

Comment: and about `cmd` the only variables that I passed are is the same one, which is the ID, I didn't get it

Comment: Yes, that query would retrieve the email as long as you get the ID passed in - it's the query I recommended a bit further up. Change the start of your PHP code so that the first line after the opening tag is `var_dump($_GET)`, and the next line is `exit()`. This will display the parameters you're passing in as part of your link. Don't go any further until they show the data you expect them to. If you right-click your page and "view source", does the link look correct to you? And is it opening the correct PHP page? `index.php` is a strange name to give the script that sends reservation emails.

Comment: Also you don't have a closing `</a>` tag on your second link, to send a rejection mail.

Comment: My server hasn't been working since yesterday, so I didn't have a chance to try it out, I hope I will soon

Comment: I did what you asked me to. I clicked on my first register and this is what I got `array(2) { ["cmd"]=> string(7) "aceitar" ["Cod_Reserva"]=> string(1) "1" }` and it didn't send the email (by the way, "aceitar" is the name of my acceptance file)

Comment: I edited the post, so you can see how I did it, and I closed the `<a>` tag

Comment: Well no, if you added the `exit()` then it won't send the email. The point of that was to just see if the information is coming through from the link. You now need to edit the query so that it retrieves only the information for that value of `Cod_Reserva` as we discussed further up. Remove the `exit()`, edit the query, display the results and exit again. Once you can see the results are correct from the query, then you can continue with sending the email.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ` "aceitar" is the name of my acceptance file`, in this case it's just another parameter that you pass through into the PHP code. Presumably at some point you'll change the PHP so that it looks at that value, and uses it to decide whether it's accepting or rejecting a reservation.

Comment: Presumably somewhere in your PHP code that you haven't shown, you include the necessary code to connect to your database prior to running a query?

Comment: No problem, glad it's sorted out for you.